# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to (my ip)

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm developing an android apps that require connection to mysql. I host wampserver using my pc as localhost. And i connect my real android device to mysql via my pc. When connecting using my home network with IP 192.168.1.x, the connection is fine and my apps works fine in retrieving and inserting data. But when I connects using other network/IP address e.g. 10.207.x.x or 192.168.0.x, it throws out error. I had been checked i have add INTERNET permission, and I try change port number in connecting e.g. http://192.168.0.1:8081/(php file directory) but it still not working. Any helps please, i have been struggling for few days.

error log:

```
04-27 22:19:23.920 4644-4740/? W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.108 (port 8085) after 15000ms
04-27 22:19:23.940 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
04-27 22:19:23.940 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
04-27 22:19:23.950 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-27 22:19:23.960 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
04-27 22:19:23.960 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
04-27 22:19:23.970 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:152)
04-27 22:19:23.980 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
04-27 22:19:23.980 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
04-27 22:19:23.990 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
04-27 22:19:24.000 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
04-27 22:19:24.000 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
04-27 22:19:24.010 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
04-27 22:19:24.020 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
04-27 22:19:24.030 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.qualcomm.vuforia.samples.SampleApplication.utils.HttpUrlConnectionParser.makehttpUrlConnection(HttpUrlConnectionParser.java:48)
04-27 22:19:24.030 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.qualcomm.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books.FeedBack$ConnectDatabase.doInBackground(FeedBack.java:182)
04-27 22:19:24.040 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at com.qualcomm.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books.FeedBack$ConnectDatabase.doInBackground(FeedBack.java:140)
04-27 22:19:24.050 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-27 22:19:24.050 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-27 22:19:24.060 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-27 22:19:24.070 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-27 22:19:24.070 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-27 22:19:24.080 4644-4740/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

my doInBackground code:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String fb_url = "http://192.168.0.108:8085/android/comment.php";
        String get_list = "http://192.168.0.108:8085/android/get_list.php";
        String get_id = "http://192.168.0.108:8085/android/get_id.php";
        data = new HashMap<>();
        String[] response = new String[]{"Response Accepted, Thanks!","Leave us some comment =)"};
        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("feedBack")) {

            String id = params[1];
            String bus = params[2];
            String depart_station = params[3];
            String arrive_station = params[4];
            String item = params[5];
            String comment = params[6];

            data.put("reported_case",id);
            data.put("reported_bus",bus);
            data.put("depart_station", depart_station);
            data.put("arrive_station", arrive_station);
            data.put("reported_item", item);
            data.put("reporter_comment", comment);

            try {
                String result = HttpUrlConnectionParser.makehttpUrlConnection(fb_url, data);
                result = null;
                return response[0];

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        } else if (method.equals("getList")) {

            try {
                String result =     HttpUrlConnectionParser.makehttpUrlConnection(get_list, data);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                boolean ssucc = json.getBoolean("ssuccess");
                boolean isucc = json.getBoolean("isuccess");
                boolean bsucc = json.getBoolean("bsuccess");

                if (!ssucc && !isucc &&!bsucc) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    JSONArray jsonArrays = json.getJSONArray("Station");
                    JSONArray jsonArrayi = json.getJSONArray("Item");
                    JSONArray jsonArrayb = json.getJSONArray("BusType");
                    final List<String> lists = new ArrayList<>();
                    final List<String> listi = new ArrayList<>();
                    final List<String> listb = new ArrayList<>();


                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayb.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject child = jsonArrayb.getJSONObject(i);
                        String childBus = child.optString("Bus");
                        listb.add(childBus);

                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrays.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject child = jsonArrays.getJSONObject(i);
                        String childId = child.optString("ID");
                        String childName = child.optString("Name");
                        lists.add(childId + " " + childName);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayi.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject child = jsonArrayi.getJSONObject(i);
                        String childId = child.optString("ID");
                        String childItem = child.optString("Item");
                        listi.add(childId + " " + childItem);

                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_text, listb);
                            adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            editBus.setAdapter(adp1);

                            ArrayAdapter<String> adp2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_text, listi);
                            adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            editItem.setAdapter(adp2);

                            ArrayAdapter<String> adp3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_text, lists);
                            adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            editStationDepart.setAdapter(adp3);
                            editStationArrive.setAdapter(adp3);
                        }
                    });

                }

                return response[1];

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if (method.equals("getId")) {

            try {
                String result = HttpUrlConnectionParser.makehttpUrlConnection(get_id, data);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                boolean fsucc = json.getBoolean("fsuccess");

                if (!fsucc) {
                    return null;
                }else{
                    JSONArray jsonArrayf = json.getJSONArray("FeedBack_id");
                    JSONObject child = jsonArrayf.getJSONObject(0);
                    String childId = child.optString("ID");

                    return childId;

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            return null;

    }
```

httpParser class:

```
public static String makehttpUrlConnection(String   url_path,HashMap<String,String> data) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_path);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQueryData(data));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        urlConnection.connect();
        is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;


            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            json = sb.toString();
            is.close();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return json;
}
```

Comment: http://192.168.0.108:8085/android/comment.php have you checked this with browser is it working ?

Comment: `and my apps works fine in retrieving and inserting data`. Well then you are done. Why would you try a different ip? Your server computer has only one ip. Or not?

Comment: @greenapps Suppose i need my apps run properly even when i connect to other network, but now it seem to bind with my home network only. When using other IP, browser is working as long as my pc connect to that network. But the phone is fail to connect to the IP which my pc is connected to as shown in error log. Everytime I connect to other network then I change my url code too, so I cant figure out what's the prob that make my connection between phone and pc fail

Comment: Or is that any setting need to be done?

Comment: About which browser are you talking?

Comment: `i need my apps run properly even when i connect to other network,`  ?? Who is connecting to another network? Network is not important. As long as android device and your server pc are in the same network. And the client uses the ip of the server computer.

Comment: yup, the prob now is when my pc and android device both connect to my home network(i.e. 192.168.1.15), it works fine. But when i connect to other network (other than the one mentioned abv), even both connect to same network it does not work, that's weird

Comment: Then have a look at the firewall.

Comment: @greenapps so is to check the firewall setting at my pc, or to check the firewall of the network that i fail to connect?

Comment: Well think about that and then decide. The whole road has to be clean and passable.

Comment: ok i'll have a try first, thx!! if i have any problem just come back to you